# Run NUnit3 tests in parallel from multiple assemblies from console runner

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-console, nunit-3.0

I want to be able to run parameterized tests from multiple assemblies in parallel using the NUnit 3 console runner. The key is that I want to be able to run the static initializers in parallel (the slow part of the tests).

I am able to get this to work using the ReSharper 10 test runner in VisualStudio. When I run the same project in the NUnit 3 console runner, the static initializers do not run in parrallel.

I created a simple unit testing solution to reproduce the issue. There are are two projects. Each project has one test class that looks like the class below. I added logging to show that the tests do not run in parallel from the console runner.

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest1
{
    public static IEnumerable Test1Static
    {
        get
        {

            Console.WriteLine($"before sleep 1 - {DateTime.Now}");
            Thread.Sleep(12000);
            Console.WriteLine($"after sleep 1 - {DateTime.Now}");
            return new List<bool> { true, true };
        }
    }

    [Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(Test1Static))]
    public void TestMethod1(bool tc)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(tc);
    }
}
```

Console runner results:

```
C:\dev>"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" "C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\testn
unit1\UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll" "C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\testnunit1\UnitTestProjec
t2\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject2.dll"
NUnit Console Runner 3.2.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Charlie Poole

Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000

Test Files
    C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\testnunit1\UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll
    C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\testnunit1\UnitTestProject2\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject2.dll

before sleep 1 - 4/6/2016 3:13:34 PM
after sleep 1 - 4/6/2016 3:13:46 PM
before sleep 2 - 4/6/2016 3:13:47 PM
after sleep 2 - 4/6/2016 3:13:59 PM

Run Settings
    WorkDirectory: C:\dev
    ImageRuntimeVersion: 4.0.30319
    ImageTargetFrameworkName: .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2
    ImageRequiresX86: False
    ImageRequiresDefaultAppDomainAssemblyResolver: False
    NumberOfTestWorkers: 8

Test Run Summary
  Overall result: Passed
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told NUnit to run the two assemblies in parallel processes. Add --process:Parallel to your command-line. Suggest reading the version 3 docs at https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki and not going by the older version documentation.

Depending on the performance, you may want to reduce the number of parallel threads per process (shown as a default of 8 on your machine) to a lower number.

Comment: I get an error "The value 'Parallel' is not valid for option '--process'". Based on https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line I tried using "--process:Multiple". That allowed the tests to run, but I got the same result as without that option. I am able to prove that the console runner is running test cases in parallel, it is just not running the static initializers for each assembly in parallel.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I meant Multiple. Two assemblies will run at the same time. If the static initialized do not depend on some external resource in common I'd expect them to run in parallel. If not, you may want to file an issue with a simple retro case.